# End of Times Summoning Spells

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

My friend and I have played several games of End of Times now and I was re-reading the rules for summoning units. I am sure that you can only summon something from the undead legions list... however I can't find it in the rules!

Is it legal for a wizard using the [Lore of Undeath](http://www.thefieldsofblood.com/2014/08/the-lore-of-undeath.html) to summon a unit/character/monster (depending on the spell) from an army other than the Undead Legions (with a few exceptions Vampires/Tomb Kings)?

If not where does it state restrictions on what can be summoned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it in the spell description. On page 15 of the Nagash book each spell states what type can be summoned and can only be "selected from the Undead Legioins army list (page 20).

Hope that helps.